# Why are Toast requests failing in Android SDK simulator? (Big Nerd Ranch Version 4)

Tags: android, sdk

I just purchased the Big Nerd Ranch's latest Android App Dev book. Early on, it appears I've disabled Toast. I reinstalled the SDK, and rebuilt the apps to no avail.

Here's The code that calls checkAnswer, as well as the checkAnswer function - which is the driver for the Toast activity.

```
    falseButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
        checkAnswer(false)
    }


    nextButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % questionBank.size
        updateQuestion()
    }


        updateQuestion()
}

    private fun updateQuestion() {
        val questionTextResId = questionBank[currentIndex].textResId
        questionTextView.setText(questionTextResId)
    }

    private fun checkAnswer(userAnswer: Boolean) {
        val correctAnswer = questionBank[currentIndex].answer

        val messageResId = if (userAnswer == correctAnswer) {
            R.string.correct_toast
        } else {
            R.string.incorrect_toast
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I must of somehow disabled the Toast for the particular emulator. As soon as I added another device in the emulator, it worked just fine.